# How to configure IPMI when installing MaaS on HPserver

Tags: ipmi

Can any one gives me a granular walk through on how to configure power management via ilo/BMC/IPMI in HP servers, using MaaS 1.7, or the latest version, lots of people stumble accross this setting, and they can not go any further, for instance if I have to edit any template files to set power management parameters, troubleshoot connectivities using tricks to make sure MaaS is powering up nodes as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the physical cables between the iLO port and the common switch that is accessible by MAAS server.

Once the node boots up using PXE, the MAAS will detect it and the POWER TYPE is automatically setup.

Comment: It works how you explain in your answer BUT my MAAS is not able to power it on, after PEX boot. Let me know if you there is any specific iLo settings for this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an old question I guess someone can find this useful (I'm not very familiar with HP servers and it took me a little to figure it out)

The following refers to iLO5 and MAAS 3.1

- Log into the iLO interface and under Security->Network activate "IPMI/DCMI over LAN" (you may want to ack the security warning).
- Keep note of the MAC address of your NIC (not the iLO card, the actual network card(s) that you will use)
- Now go on MAAS and open Add HW->Machine.
- Fill up the form and insert your NIC MAC address
- On Power type the option is "HP Moonshot - iLO4 (IPMI).
- Under "Power Address" put the iLO card IP address, the fill in the username/pw fields
- DO NOT fill the mandatory "Power hardware address" with the MAC address of your iLO card. If you do so the scrip will fail. Simply put a single blank space and save the changes.

At this point your server should start and go through the standard commissioning procedure.